# Unable to log into encrypted root drive after running virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, encryption

I am unable to log into my encrypted hard drive on the host which is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop. This all happened after I did the following.

1. Ran VirtualBox
2. Created a VDI drive
3. Installed Kali Linux (*When asked if I would like to encrypt the whole drive I said yes*)

After Khali was installed it went all haywire and I deleted the Kali Linux virtual machine with its files and shutdown the host as normal. This morning when I powered up the pc I was unable to use my default password to access my hosts’ hard drive.

Was there a way that Kali might have re-encrypted the drive? Because I was under the impression that it was only die 8.5 gig VDI drive that was encrypted. Is there a way that I can restore Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to a previous state before Khali was installed on the virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think your Kali guest would have had **any** impact on your host HD is if somehow you have shared folders configured. But even so, sounds a bit far fetched.

Was there anything else happening recently? A system upgrade?

As for VBox and your Kali guest, the "HD" of the guest itself is only a file (or several, depends, irrelevant ATM) and whatever you do to that "HD" should have no impact on the host's partitions.

With more info maybe more people can help. Good luck!

Comment: I updated Ubuntu before the Kali installation. While it was installing I was in no network connection mode on the host.
I have tried the usual encryption access password at the startup screen with no luck.

The random encryption recovery passphrase that Ubuntu generates when one first installs Ubuntu… How does that work and how do you use the Ubuntu generated passphrase that it ask one to print or write down? Just a thought maybe I can gain access to my hard drive again that way.